# excel 2003: How can I reference a named range from a cell?

Tags: excel, range

If I have a named range "Range" that I want to reference in a formula with the name retrieved from a cell.  So for example if in cell A1 I have the text 'Range'.  How would I use that in a vlookup formula as follows:

```
=VLOOKUP(A7,Range,7,FALSE)
```

If I try replacing Range with A1 i get a #name error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
=VLOOKUP(A7,INDIRECT(A1),7,FALSE)
```

assuming your cell `A1` contains text with name of named range: `"Range"`.

But note, that since `INDIRECT` is a [volatile function](http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsi.htm), your formula would be recalculated each time any cell on the sheet changed